# Django how to raise validation error if foreignkey objects id change in hidden input

Tags: python, django

I have an hidden foreigkey filed in my forms. I want to raise validation error or stop submitting forms if user try to change the value. here is my code:

**html:**

```
 {%for i in user_profile%}
       <input type="hidden" name='userprofile' value="{{i.id}}">
 {%endfor%}
```

**models.py:**

```
class BlogComment(MPTTModel):
      userprofile= models.ForeignKey(UserProfile,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
      #my others model fields...
```

**views.py:**

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

I want to raise validation error if current id change in hidden input. how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use validation in django form and check if gotten user profile id is not equal to current user id

First, pass user to form in your `views.py`:

```py
form = UserProfileForm(user=request.user)
...
```

Then use passed user in `forms.py`:

```py
from django import forms
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class UserProfileForm(forms.Form):
    userprofile = IntegerField()
    ...

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def clean(self):
        if cleaned_data.get("userprofile") != self.user.id:
            raise ValidationError(...)
```

You can see more about form validation in

Comment: not working getting 'CommentFrom' object has no attribute 'request' error

Comment: Sorry. I've updated my answer. hope works now @boyenec

Answer (score 0):

Simple, In your views.py

```
user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
if user_profile.id != request.POST.get('userprofile'):
   raise ValidationError(...)
```

usually I prefer return instead of raise like

```
return JsonResponse
return redirect
```

mostly for error handling for same page

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Comment: 'int' object has no attribute 'id' getting this error

Comment: Ah not Filter, use get,

Comment: Haseeb Ahmed still now same errror 'int' object has no attribute 'id'